# redirect to profile page

Tags: php

I am having difficulty redirecting to the home page when someone logs in. I successfully complete the login form and nothing seems to happen i just stay on the same page. I cant spot the mistake any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php

include("scripts/connect.php");

$form = "<form action='home.php' method='post'>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='email' class='textbox' size='35'></td>
        <td><a href='register.php'>Register?</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='password' class='textbox' size='35'></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='login' value='Login' class='button' alt='Login'></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>";


if ($_POST['login']){
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

if ($email && $password){

require("scripts/connect.php");

$pass = md5(md5($password));

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if ($numrows == 1){

                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                $dbid = $row['uid'];
                $dbuser = $row['name'];

                $_SESSION['name'] = $dbuser;
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;


                header("profile.php?uid=$userid");

            }
            else
                echo "Your login information was incorrect! $form";
    }
    else
        echo "You did not fill in the entire form! $form";
}
else
    echo "$form";


  ?>
```

Session variable in header.

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
header("profile.php?uid=$userid");
```

You're missing the most important part:

```
header( "Location: profile.php?uid=$userid" );
```

Additionally, as Pavel pointed out in the comments below, your User ID is not stored in `$userid`.

```
$dbid = $row['uid'];
...
header( "Location: profile.php?uid=$dbid" );
```

Lastly, it wouldn't be fair to you if I didn't point out the potential for SQL Injection in your query. You are selecting all rows from the users table whose email and password match up. However, if I were to pass in the following as my email address, and guess a random password, I would get access:

```
' or 'a' = 'a
```

Joining this with your query, the query to the database now becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='' or 'a' = 'a' AND password='$pass'"
```

At this point, I can guess a random password, and as long as the password is used by somebody in  your database, I will be authenticated as the first user in the result set. If passwords were too hard, but I knew the email addresses of some of your users (not hard, since those are very easy to come by), I could reverse it:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='admin@domain.com' AND password='' OR 'a' = 'a'
```

Again, here, it doesn't matter what your password is, since I no longer require it. If 'a' = 'a' (and it always does), then the password is no longer required. I would be logged in as the first user to have the provided email address.

Even worse:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '' OR 'a'='a' AND password = '' OR 'a' = 'a'
```

This will log me in as the first user returned, which is often times the administrator.

Comment: I made this change at it still remains on the same page. ill post the header which has the session variables.

Comment: Is the `header('Location:...')` even redirecting the user. Or when you say you're staying on the same page, do you mean you are not passing authentication, and are therefore being sent back to the login page?

Comment: The login script is on the home page. what i have posted. So to the eye nothing seems to happen, what you can see remains the same once you hit the login button.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!. What would be a safer way to write this, i don't have a lot of experience building safe websites which must be obvious. The more pointers the better!.

Comment: @KCCMan For more info on SQLInjection, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection.

Answer (score 0):

The `header` function in PHP allows you to set the page header. In your case you are not specifying anything for the header. You can use the `header()` special case `Location` to tell the browser to do a redirect to the desired url.

This will push a 302 response to the browser and do the redirect. So your code should look something like this:

```
header("Location: http://example.com");
```

Make sure you don't have any outputs before calling this method, because it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing

```
if ($_POST['login']){
```

to:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
```

?

And use the header redirect like this:

```
header("Location: page.php");
```