# PHP/HTML - profile page WITHOUT login but from navigation links

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

After looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298588/redirect-to-profile-page) I'm still confused. Essentially, I have a navigation bar in html. One section is say 'people', and under this are the different people extracted from a mysql database.

e.g.

```
-people
--john wayne
--tom adams
--etc
```

My links in the html code is "people/johnwayne.html" where johnwayne is another variable for the link in the database.

instead of having these links, i'm looking to use e.g. profile.php page, how would i generate this? I see links like

```
somedomain.com/profile.php?uid=$userid
```

In the link above which I saw first, they have something like this

```
header( "Location: profile.php?uid=$userid" );
```

I can connect to database, do sql queries etc fine. How do I go about gathering this id on a new page if it is clear

---

EDIT:
Just to clarify with some sample code, here is the menu,

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li>
      <a href="/people/johnwayne.html" title="John Wayne">John Wayne</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/people/tomadams.html" title="Tom Adams">Tom Adams</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

johnwayne is an element from a table in a mysql database called 'link', so is the 'title' etc.
I don't want separate johnwayne.html, tomadams.html pages, but all the links will be of the form

```
"people/profile.php?uid=$link"
e.g. "people/profile.php?uid=johnwayne"
```

Or however it is done.
In other words, profile.php will generate some file look at the row of 'johnwayne', and get all data to generate a html page that is generic for all people

Answer (score 0):

You will GET the variables using PHP that looks like this:

```
$user = $_GET['userid'];
```

But you will also promise to sanitize this variable before trying to stick it into a MySQL database query, okay? :) Something like this:

```
$userClean = addslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($user));
```

Or better yet, using a "whitelist" of acceptable options. For example, if you KNOW that you only have five people, do this:

```
$user = $_GET['userid'];
if($user == 'shredder') {
  include('shredder.html');
} else if($user == 'splinter') {
  include('splinter.html');
} else if($user == 'turtles') {
  include('cowabunga.html');
}
```

Safety first! :)

Comment: thanks for your reply, still a tad bit confused but i modified my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn a server side scripting language like php or perl, and because my display name says I-love-PHP I suggest **PHP**.

The content following '?' is sent using the http GET request, 
If you are new, Remember the good old method=GET/POST in html forms??

This will get you started

http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp